# body: overflow-x - still able to scroll over with trackpad

Tags: css, overflow, css-position, trackpad

I have a div with `position: absolute` set and it's just a tad bit wider than my browser window.  I've successfully hidden the horizontal scroll bar, but I am still able to scroll over with a **Macbook** trackpad.

Is there any way to circumvent this?

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="big-image"></div>
</div><!-- #container -->

#container {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#big-image {
    background: transparent url('/path/to/image.png') no-repeat center top;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1307px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 0 0 0 -653.5px;
    z-index: 4;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're not limiting the height of #container, just set overflow to hidden, as overflow-x is strange in that it removes the scroll bar, yet still allows you to scroll.

**Example**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

#container {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but there is a slight issue when the window is small enough to where the _content area_ causes the horizontal scrollbar to appear.  That is, you can scroll over but the image I was using is cut off and it's just white where the image should go..  Still though, thanks!  For now, I've worked around it with JS but can it be done with pure CSS?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're referring to by content area :S Perhaps set the overflow property of it to hidden as well?

Comment: I just realized I never responded to your question. I don't remember what I was working on at the time but I think I can explain.  Technically I never figured this out completely and I still have my JS workaround in place lol.

Comment: This solved my problem, thanks! I needed to put overflow-x:hidden on both the html element, and the body element, to stop the side scrolling being allowed.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably use `position: fixed;` on the `#big-image`.

Comment: User still needs to scroll _down_, and `position: fixed` will keep the div planted at the top even after scrolling. but thanks anyway.

Comment: Kind a difficult to help you out when I don't know your requirements.

Comment: Sorry, I appreciate your intent to help though! :)